# Cannot change Page name on Facebook

Tags: facebook-pages

When I try to rename my page on my phone, I get the following error consistently:

> "The page you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may be broken or expired, or you may not have permission to view this page."

I have tried using the desktop computer. I don't see any option to change name of the page

I am the only page admin. Please let me know what can be done.

Comment: This site is not right place for the issues which you are seeing on mobile. Try from a laptop or desktop using a web browser and let us know what error you are seeing. Attaching screenshot would be more helpful.

Comment: I have tried that.

Comment: _I don't see any option to change name of the page_, when you click on edit button page, what it says?

Comment: This is possible only on the desktop version of Facebook.